# Trouble Adding Library Package Reference to NUnit in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, nuget

I want to add a library package reference to NUnit so that I can do some unit testing. When I try to download the package and add the reference, I get this error:

The schema version of 'NUnit' is incompatible with version 1.2.20325.9034 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.

So then I go to this URL and download the file NuGet.Tools.vsix. When I double click it, I get the error: "Invalid command line arguments." So I then run Web Platform Installer 3.0, but I can't figure out how to upgrade NuGet from there either. Finally, I was able to install version 1.6.2 of NuGet.Core from inside of Visual Web Developer via "Add Library Package Reference" under the Project menu. However, when I try to install NUnit the same way, it still gives me the error that it is incompatible with version 1.2... of NuGet, even though it appears that Nuget.Core is now upgraded to version 1.6.2!

Any idea what is going on?

I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express on Windows 7. Also, I am using wpilauncher_3_10.exe.

Comment: This got me sorted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8483665/56145

Answer (score 0):

I followed this web site [Link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues)
In order to unistalling nuget follow  [Visual Studio 2010 - Uninstall NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802694/visual-studio-2010-uninstall-nuget)

And you can download and install nuget from here [download Nuget](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c)