# Possible bug in Visual Studio Tool VSIXInstaller

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

i am running in an exception when I want to update extensions in Visual Studio 2015. Each and every time I am updating an extension I will get an file is already in use exception. I tracked this down to the file *.pkgdef.

I am running in this exception on my working pc only. This machine runs Windows 8.1 with McAfee Antivirus, Firewall and Drive Encryption. I have the feeling that drive encryption has something to do with this exception but I can not say this for sure.

I debugged VSIXInstaller and found something that I believe is a bug.
The class is ExtensionManagerService.cs in the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation.dll .

```
private void AtomicallyDeleteFiles(IEnumerable<string> filePaths, bool justMarkForDeletion)
{
  foreach (FileStream fileStream in this.LockFiles(filePaths, (IList<string>) null))
  {
    if (justMarkForDeletion)
    {
      string str = fileStream.Name + ".deleteme";
      File.Delete(str);
      File.Move(fileStream.Name, str);
    }
    else
      File.Delete(fileStream.Name);
    fileStream.Close();
  }
}
```

The LockFiles method is implemented as followed:

```
private IEnumerable<FileStream> LockFiles(IEnumerable<string> filePaths, IList<string> inUse = null)
{
  List<FileStream> list = new List<FileStream>();
  foreach (string path in filePaths)
  {
    try
    {
      FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);
      if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
      {
        FileAttributes fileAttributes = attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        File.SetAttributes(path, fileAttributes);
      }
      FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Delete);
      list.Add(fileStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      if (ex is FileNotFoundException)
      {
        try
        {
          Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\Extensibility\\ExtensionSDKDeletionListStore\\", "ScanForDeleteMeExtensionSDKsAtStartup", (object) 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
          Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\Extensibility\\ExtensionSDKDeletionListStore\\", "ScanForDeleteMeExtensionSDKsAtStartup", (object) 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
      }
      if (inUse == null)
      {
        foreach (Stream stream in list)
          stream.Close();
        throw;
      }
      else
        inUse.Add(path);
    }
  }
  return (IEnumerable<FileStream>) list;
}
```

The exception happens at File.Move in AtomicallyDeleteFiles. I think that at that point a File.Copy was intended to be used. The file can not be moved because it was locked in the first place.

What I could not determine is why this only happens on my McAfee machine. But this problem was reported also here [Can't Update or Uninstall NuGet Package Manager in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714619/cant-update-or-uninstall-nuget-package-manager-in-vs2012) and here http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/07/30/upgrading-nuget-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it.aspx/.

I do not know how can I get in touch with the Visual Studio Team. Would you consider this a bug too ? Can anyone help me reporting this ?

Regards
T4E

Comment: How did you get the source code for ExtensionManagerService.cs out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the proper place to put feedback to Visual Studio is [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback). It's unfortunate that VS is not open source so you can't offer them pull request. I suffer from the same issue and your finding seems reasonable -- although the fact that I too have McAfee on my machine is suspicious.

Comment: I put this on Connect. But it seems no one cares ... :-(
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1741462/bug-in-vsixinstaller