# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 is restarting when installing or uninstalling nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

My problem is that Visual Studio 2013 is restarting all the time when i want to install or uninstall package from solution, project.For an example I clicked Manage my package and when i want to install this package to other project all is going fine but after 5 seconds i have message "Not responding" and visual is crash.I tried to reinstall nuget tool but it doesn't work.

In comment below i put screens what i have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Update or Uninstall NuGet Package Manager in VS2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714619/cant-update-or-uninstall-nuget-package-manager-in-vs2012)

Comment: Not work. I reinstall nuget in safe mode windows 10 and this not solved my problem. I have this: [link](http://scr.hu/2jo0/citoo) [link](http://scr.hu/2jo0/g1k9u) [link](http://scr.hu/2jo0/2ivz3) . Always restarting visual don't know what to do :(