# TFS NuGet Packager: [error] 'System.Runtime' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms'

Tags: tfs, nuget

I am using the [NuGet Packager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OveAndersen.NuGetPackager) task as part of my TFS 2017 build procedure to create a NuGet package for a class library. I am getting the error:

> [error]'System.Runtime' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms'.
>   [error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

I set the following task parameters:

```
Path to csproj or nuspec file(s) to pack: .\xxx\xxx.csproj
Package Folder: ./xxx/bin/Release
Include referenced projects: Checked
Automatic package versioning: Use the build number
Configuration to Package: $(BuildConfiguration)
```

I am using the same TFS task to create another NuGet package for another class library, and everything works fine.

I tried solutions provided by the following stackoverflow questions, but nothing worked.

[TFS2015 NuGet Packager: [error] 'System.Collections' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522843/tfs2015-nuget-packager-error-system-collections-already-has-a-dependency-de)

[NuGet: 'X' already has a dependency defined for 'Y'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)

Any idea on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported at ['System.Globalization' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms'](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3530), this error has been fixed in the new multi-purpose **NuGet Command** task that supersedes the old **NuGet Packager** task and uses NuGet 4.0 by default.

Using the **NuGet Command** TFS task in place of the **NuGet Packager** TFS task fixed the error. The parameters used with the **NuGet Command** task are:

```
Command: pack
Arguments: .\xxx\xxx.csproj 
    -OutputDirectory ./xxx/bin/Release
    -Version $(Build.BuildNumber)
    -IncludeReferencedProjects
    -Properties Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration)
```