# 'Twilio' already has a dependency

Tags: asp.net

I'am new to asp.net and really hoping for help, well you see I'am trying to Install twilio but this error shows

```
'Twilio' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging'.
```

Comment: take a look if this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532170/newtonsoft-json-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-microsoft-csharp

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me... thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user202729 after giving it a second more detailed look I think you're right. Will remove the vote for duplication.