# 'Dapper' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: model-view-controller, dapper

[image]

When i tried to install dapper in VS2012 i got this error.

Comment: Why don't you just paste the actual text so it is easier to read?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725545/nuget-x-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-y

Answer (score 4):

Please try version 1.50.0 of Dapper. It seems the latest version of Dapper doesn't support VS2012.

Comment: follow your request.