# Nexmo Api installation failed in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, api, vonage

I want to install Nexmo Api from NugetPackage in Visual Studio 2013 but showing this error [image]

I change targetframework from 4.5 to **3.0,3.5**,**4.5.1**,**4.6.1** and **4.5** and test with each of them but not working with any of target framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the latest NuGet Package Manager ?

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca

Don't forget to restart VisualStudio.

---

Original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25844391/8819015)