# Nuget: 'Google.Apis' already has a dependency defined for 'Google.Apis.Core'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, installation, nuget

I'm facing the following error in NuGet while trying to install package `Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v3 -Version 1.37.0.1470`. Showing following Error:

```
Install-Package : 'Google.Apis' already has a dependency defined for 'Google.Apis.Core'.
At line:1 char:17
+ Install-Package <<<< Google.Apis.Drive.v3 -Version 1.37.0.1470
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

if i install previous version `Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2`. Also showing same Error:

```
Install-Package : 'Google.Apis' already has a dependency defined for 'Google.Apis.Core'.
    At line:1 char:17
    + Install-Package <<<< Google.Apis.Drive.v2
       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, .net framework 4.5 and NuGet package manager 2.8.6031.8.667. Please help me how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nuget: 'Google.Apis' already has a dependency defined for 'Google.Apis.Core'

Since your nuget version is `2.8.6031.8.667`, the highest version of the package you can install `Google.Apis.Drive.v3` is **1.25.0.862**.

**Detailed Reason:**

The package `Google.Apis.Drive.v3` have following dependencies list:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3 (>= 1.37.0.1470)

                  ----Google.Apis (>= 1.37.0)

                             ----Google.Apis.Core (>= 1.37.0)

                                             ----Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.2)
```

Since the dependency package `Newtonsoft.Json (>= 10.0.2)` introduces the .netstandard dependencies:

[image]

This is only supported by the nuget **2.12** and above. That the reason why you got that error info, check the similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725545/nuget-x-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-y).

So, **to resolve this issue**, please try to install the a lower version of package version `Google.Apis.Drive.v3` **1.25.0.862**. I have test it with Visual Studio 2012 on my side, and it works fine.

Besides, if you want to install a later version of that package, you need to update you Visual Studio to **2013**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank for reply. this version 1.25.0.862 is install perfectly. thank you