# Error while pushing to private NuGet repository: 'X' already has a dependency defined for 'Y'

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

While pushing my own `.nupkg` file to my private nuget repository, I encountered HTTP 500. Upon inspecting in Fiddler, I found this error message along the line of 'X' already has a dependency defined for 'Y'.

This is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725545/nuget-x-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-y?noredirect=1&lq=1), but instead of happening during nuget `add`, this one happens upon nuget `push`. I did make sure that my nuget.exe locally is on version 4+.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this is caused by the `.nupkg` that I'm trying to push having .NET Core dependencies defined along with .NET Framework dependencies. This is incompatible with older version of nuget ***server*** that was running in my private repository.

Similar to the problem happening on the nuget `add`, I have to ensure that my private nuget ***server*** is updated to a version that supports .NET Core dependencies. In my case, I updated the Nuget.Server to [3.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/)

Bear in mind that updating the `NuGet.Server` also mutates the Web.config which might cause the server failing to start with HTTP 500. To resolve, I also had to remove the extraneous duplicate `<compilation>` and `<apikey>` element as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server#create-and-deploy-an-aspnet-web-application-with-nugetserver).