# Signalr installation issue from VS2010 IDE

Tags: signalr

i try to install signalr from my vs2010 ide like this way but got this error

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS (≥ 2.1.2)' not installed. Attempting to retrieve dependency from source...
Done.
Install-Package : The schema version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS' is incompatible with version 1.2.20325.9034 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://
go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

i install the nuget package again and issued this command at package manager console and got this error

```
install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3
The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\TRIDIP\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find version '1.1.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the first of your two error messages your nuget manager version is too old. The current version is 2.8.3 (as of November 2014). The version you are running is 1.2.2. It seems like this is a known 'thing' with other packages in nuget (see. [NuGet Package Manager errors when trying to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483624/nuget-package-manager-errors-when-trying-to-update/8483665#8483665)) you will need to update to the newer version. By the looks of it this will require an uninstall of the nuget visx (visual studio extension) and install the latest version (available from here: http://www.nuget.org/).

**[UPDATE] OP wanted to know how to install manually:**

If you download the current version (from here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/zipball/master) and unzip the filesthen you can add these into your project manually. Assuming you are doing an MVC project add the js files to the scripts folder, anything else can just go into the project. Then follow this link for a quick start: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr.

The SignalR source code is also available, you can clone it from here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Its probably worth taking the time to update your nuget version rather than doing everything manually as you will be able to use it for other packages and get updates to signalr when they are made too.

Comment: Based on the first of your two error messages its a problem with your version of nuget. When you updated nuget did you uninstall/reinstall or just update?

Comment: how to manually add signalr related js and assembly for VS2010 project...guidance would help me. thanks

Comment: have updated my answer to include link to signalR files

Comment: Nuget problem is not solved so i have to manually add signalr related dependency. thanks

Comment: @Mou if there is nothing else I can help you with can you mark my response as the answer